# HTML: Meta description tag's uses

Tags: html, meta-tags

I'm working on a web site that is only used internally in the company, and the only way to get to site is in a popup window launched by different web site. Is there any reason I should include a `<meta name="description" content="blah blah" /`> tag? Besides search engines what other reason is there to have a description meta tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an internal site there is no reason to add a `description` meta tag. It is indeed for search engine usage, so unless you are using an internal search engine (say a [google mini](http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/mini.html)) this is entirely unneeded.

From wikipedia - [the description attribute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_element#The_description_attribute):

> The description attribute provides a concise explanation of a Web page's content. This allows the Web page authors to give a more meaningful description for listings than might be displayed if the **search engine** was unable to automatically create its own description based on the page content.

(emphasis mine)